# C# - generic type with multiple types, includes a type with a type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following generic class:

```
public class DomainValidator<TRequest> : IValidator<TRequest> where TRequest : IRequest, IRequest<object>
{
}
```

As you can see, I have 2 types specified for type of `TRequest`: `IRequest` with no type, and `IRequest<object>` with a type of any.

If I use this `DomainValidator` class anywhere, Visual Studio compiler always complains that the type is not convertable to type `IRequest`, because it has it's own type parameter.

I have looked at other similar questions, but none of them have a type parameter, which has it's own type. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to achieve?

**UPDATE**

Here is how I am using this generic class and where it fails.

The following class `RequestThatDoesntWorkValidator` does not work, because `RequestThatDoesntWork` does not provide a type for `IRequest` as it doesn't need to:

```
public class RequestThatDoesntWorkValidator : DomainValidator<RequestThatDoesntWork>
{

}

public class RequestThatDoesntWork : IRequest
{

}
```

But the following class `RequestThatDoesWorkValidator` seems to work because `RequestThatDoesWork` provides a type for `IRequest`:

```
public class RequestThatDoesWorkValidator : DomainValidator<RequestThatDoesWork>
{

}

public class RequestThatDoesWork : IRequest<List<string>>
{

}
```

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Can you please post a code snippet that shows us what exactly doesn't compile? It sounds like you are trying to cast a DomainValidator to an IRequest, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JohnWu please see my updated queston.

Comment: When you say "I have 2 types specified for type of `TRequest`", do you want `TRequest` to implement *both* the listed interfaces, or *either* of the listed interfaces? Because what you've got at the moment requires `TRequest` to satisfay *both* the listed interfaces. In fact, you can't actually say 'require `TRequest` to implement `IRequest` *or* `IRequest<>`'.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541173/71059 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891656/non-strict-multiple-interface-type-parameter-constraints

Comment: @AakashM thank you, that's what I was looking for. I needed a base interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a type parameter to your own type to pass as that nested parameter:

```
public class DomainValidator<TRequest, TInner> : IValidator<TRequest> 
       where TRequest : IRequest, IRequest<TInner>
```

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.